# Break / Split / Extract string into parts

Tags: c++, string

I have what seems to be a very simple problem but I can not seem to wrap my head around the issue...

I have a string lets call it `"HELLOWORLD"`, and I have a number that is generated from some other work I do, lets say it is `4`

How do I return the first (`"HELL"`) and maintain the second (`"OWORLD"`)to work on?

Comment: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Im working in C++ and I would like to return the first and maintain the second to work on.

Comment: Generally you should include your current code with questions like this... And tell what it does and how it is different from what you want.

Comment: I having trouble understanding why this is such a difficult task.  Does anybody research the `std::string` library?  There's been a lot of these related questions in the last few weeks!

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the index where you wish to split, then the easiest way would be to use the string constructor that takes two iterators:

```
std::string original = "HELLOWORLD";

std::size_t index = 4;
std::string::iterator it = original.begin();

std::string part1(it, it + index);
std::string part2(it + index, original.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
#include <string>
...

string thing = "HELLOWORLD";

thing.substr(0, 4);    // => "HELL"
```

The `substr` method (from the `string` library) returns a string from the first index to (but excluding) the second index passed to it.

**UPDATE**

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly you want to do. If you want to get the *end* of the string (i.e. `"OWORLD"`), you could do something like:

```
thing.substr(4, thing.length())   // => "OWORLD"
```

This looks from the 4th index (inclusively) to the Nth index (exclusively).